# Beautiful numbers wave in associative arrays

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am actually working on a 'ground metrics engine' for a game. What I basically do is copying the real map data into another associative array, and map it with some metrics attribute like fertility or humidity, here is a sample code:

```
this.metricsMap = {};
this.generatedFertilities = {};

for (var i = 0; i < this.groundMap.data.length; i++) {
    this.generatedFertilities[i] = this.groundMap.data[i].map(function () {
        // TODO
    });
}

for (var i = 0; i < this.groundMap.data.length; i++) {
    this.metricsMap[i] = this.generatedFertilities[i].map(function (res) {
        return {
            ownedBy: "",
            fertility: res,
            humidity: 50
        }
    });
}
```

The map data is as an associative array [32][32]. I want to generate the corresponding 'fertility matrix' with consistency and 'number waves', here is a big picture of what I want to try to make on a smaller associative array:

```
[68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 74, 73],
[69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72],
[70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71],
[71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 60],
[72, 73, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 60, 59],
[73, 74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 60, 59, 58],
[74, 75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 60, 59, 58; 57],
[75, 74, 73, 72, 71, 60, 59, 58; 57, 56],
[74, 73, 72, 71, 60, 59, 58; 57, 56, 55],
[73, 72, 71, 60, 59, 58; 57, 56, 55, 54]
```

We can imagine more 'pattern' where there is more concentration in the middle of the matrix for example.

I tried a lot of things things like this :

```
var baseRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
for (var i = 0; i < this.groundMap.data.length; i++) {
    var counter = 0;
    this.generatedFertilities[i] = this.groundMap.data[i].map(function () {
        counter++;

        // think of i like the y axis and counter like the x axis
        if(i % 8 == 0){
            if(counter < 8){
                return Math.abs(Math.floor(baseRand++));
            } else {
                return Math.abs(Math.floor(baseRand--));
            }
        } else {
            if(counter > 8){
                return Math.abs(Math.floor(baseRand--));
            } else {
                return Math.abs(Math.floor(baseRand++));
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But this doesn't get me somewhere and I am in trouble with the math behind it. How would you guys design such an algorithm ?

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure if I understand your problem correctly. Are you tied to real map data?

If not maybe [Perlin Noise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) is something that can help you. Such noise functions can easily be used for terrain generation in games. You just have to map the color values to height values.

Comment: No, i am not tied to real map data